# How can I view updated data cells in Excel in a shared workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is there a way to view updated data in a shared workbook without having to write a macro or closing and reopening Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Shared Workbook updating in Excel 2007+:

Go to the Review Tab, Changes section and click on Share Workbook.
Click on the Advanced Tab, and in the Update changes section select `Automatically` and `Just see other users' changes` as shown:

[image: Shared Workbook Dialog]

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't quite work with Excel 2007 and also it only works with formulas. I need all the data to be updated automatically be it text, calculations, etc

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, answer updated, I'll edit your question to make it clearer what you wanted.